# How to allow all java plugins on whole site?

Tags: google-chrome, java-applet

I am solving go problems on http://www.goproblems.com/ . They are made by java applets. For example http://www.goproblems.com/7858 . Everytime I click on some of them I see "Do you want to run this application?" If I set "do not show this for this app" and click "Run" it allows just one of them. I want to allow all applets at once on the site not one by one. How can I do it in Chrome?

It would be nice if it could be done by some regular expression. So I can allow some applets of some kind of subpages and do not automatically allow others.

P.S.: Is it possible to change starting position of that security warning window?

Comment: Considering the wicked set of exploits plaguing Java lately, are you sure you want to let your browser run it without warning you first?

Comment: It is site I believe. Not just any site. I will always click on run on that applets. What is difference if I do it manually or make it automatically?

Comment: The difference would be that having your browser automatically load all Java applets would be a giant security hole, as @AlEverett suggested. Malicious code would be loaded without you knowing it.

Comment: I do not want all applets. I want one kind of applets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a fellow Go player, I am plagued by the same problem myself.

I did not find any way to solve this. The problem seems to be caused by improper programming of the site itself and ought to be fixed by the site author... so I contacted him: http://goproblems.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=928

Answer (score 0):

Chrome has an extension for MSIE. When I run into sites that require JAVA, I just click on the extension icon and the site opens in a simulated MSIE page, and uses all MSIE configurations, including Java.  Download extension at: [https://chrome.google.com/webstore/search/MSIE](http://MSIE%20Extension)

The only thing I have found to defeat the 'no java' problem.